# How to use SlowCheetah to transform an array elements in Json config file?

Tags: arrays, json, slowcheetah

It's my first time using SlowCheetah for JSON config file. I could not find a way to let it transform an array settings. For example, if my base config file has this setting:

```
{
  "Settings" :  [1, 2, 3] 
}
```

and I want to transfer it to:

```
{
  "Settings" :  [4, 5, 6] 
}
```

It simply does the merge, instead of replacement. Is there a way I can tell it what to do? Like the way we using xdt:Transform="Replace" in xml config file.

Answer (score 10):

This transformation will do the job:

```
{
  "@jdt.replace": {
    "@jdt.path": "$.Settings",
    "@jdt.value": [4,5,6]
  }
}
```

Comment: More info on Json document transforms - https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. Really appreciated !

Comment: @Collin_K Is it possible to do a transform for a **single** element rather than for the complete array? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780767/

Comment: @B--rian Not as far as I know. I have only ever replaced entire arrays.